# BinaryTree count leaves infinite loof

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

I wrote countLeaf method in my binary tree class to count every leaves from root.

However, it gave me stack overflow error, but I couldn't figure what I did wrong.

this is the countLeaf class from my binaryTree

```
public int countLeaf(Node node){
      if(root == null){return 0;} // this part work when I create null Tree
      else if(root.left == null && root.right == null){
         return 1; //this work when I create tree without left and right
      }
         else {
         System.out.print(root.data); // check infinite loop
         return countLeaf(root.left) + countLeaf(root.right);
      }
 }
```

And this is my main

```
public static void main (String[] args){
      BinaryTree a = new BinaryTree("A?", 
                     new BinaryTree("B?",
                        new BinaryTree("D"),
                        new BinaryTree("E")), 
                     new BinaryTree("C?",
                        new BinaryTree("E"), 
                        new BinaryTree("F")));          
      System.out.print(a);
      int n = a.countLeaf(a.root);
   }
```

and when I run it, it gave me

A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A?A? ... and stackoverflow error

why it keep repeating original root instead of follow left or right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `public int countLeaf(Node node)` with `public int countLeaf(Node root)`.

I believe it will help.

Anyways, variable **node** is never used.